# Java Android Remove the outline of items in a recyclervciew

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am developing an activity that searches for users in my Firebase realtime DB and I am using a cradview as a layout to inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/crdProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/textC"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/user_default"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/crdProfileImage"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="Hi, this is my biography."/>




    </RelativeLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

However, I noticed that when the recyclerview outputs the items, the items appear with an outline:

[image]

I thought it was the elevation, so I set it to 0, both on the recyclerview and on the layout in the cardview, but the result didn't change. Would anyone know how to solve?

EDIT:

I tried to remove the margin bottom but it still shows the elevation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/crdProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/textC"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHolder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/user_default"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/crdProfileImage"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtBio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtUsername"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="Hi, this is my biography."/>




    </RelativeLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line of code to disable the `outlineProvider`:

```
android:outlineProvider="none"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
```

Instead of

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: I just tried but while removing the elevation in the cardview it does not remove the elevation from the cardviews when they are items in the recyclerview output, the elevation only takes away from the item layout. I don't know if I've made myself clear

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the `android:elevation` being `0dp` just remove the `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"` from your `<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView />` and then add `android:padding` for your children view in it to make the spacing

Comment: I just tried to do this (I posted the updated code in the question) but it doesn't work

Comment: can you make the height of the MaterialCardView to wrap content and try again, the relative layout must have height of wrap content as well